# AlmaLinux 9/RHEL and nftables : Keep getting "type filter hook input priority filter" at chain

Tags: nftables, rhel8

Good day to all!

First of all, i have to say i'm a Linux novice and new to StackExchange so i hope i'm asking my question the right way.

I would like to use nftables as firewall on a new AlmaLinux installation (v9.1, minimal install, headless management and security tools).  To avoid getting firewalld in the way, i disabled firewalld with:

'''

```
    # systemctl disable firewalld
    # systemctl stop firewalld
    # systemctl mask firewalld
```

'''

Then installed and updated the nfs package to 1.0.4-2-el9 and started the service with:

'''

```
    # systemctl enable nftables
    # systemctl start nftables
```

'''

My intention was to create separate tables for ip(v4) and ip6 (rather than using inet), as i don't want to use ip6. When creating a separate ip6 table, i could use that to drop all ip6 traffic and focus on managing ip(v4) in it's own ip table. Set up is 2 interfaces, one for incoming WAN traffic (after it passed the firewall/router) and one facing the LAN incl. management of the server. Currently the interfaces are both on 10.0.0.0/24 but when i would like to create a DMZ i would only have to configure the WAN interface for the DMZ.

So, i created the tables with:

'''

```
    # nft add table ip firewall4
    # nft add table ip6 firewall6
    # nft list tables
```

'''

confirms existence of both tables.

I added a new chain and checked it's contents with:

'''

```
    # nft add chain ip6 firewall6 input { type filter hook input priority 0\; }
    # nft list table ip6 firewall6
```

'''

The output i keep getting (no matter what i do or change) is:

'''

```
     table ip6 firewall6 {
        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        }
}
```

'''

When i try another priority (e.g. 1), i get "type filter hook input priority filter +1; policy. Deleting and inserting the chain again by type the full command (not just up up)

Everywhere, in all examples/how-to's/documentation i see "priority 0". I'm not sure if "priority filter" is correct and fear that the chain and rules to be added might be ignored as obviously "filter" is different than "0" and i don't understand how "filter" would be prioritized with other chains in same table.

So my questions are:

1. Is "priority filter" OK, or will it change when i add more to the table?
2. If not OK, what could/should i do to get a value at priority?

Many thanks in advance to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword `filter` translates to 0 and vice-versa when used as a chain priority (except in a bridge family where values differ a bit). Previous versions of `nftables` didn't display this. Newer version do. There's no change in its role.

To avoid the output resolving the priority, as described in the [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#OPTIONS):

> `-y`, `--numeric-priority`
>
> Display base chain priority numerically.

That would be:

```
nft -y list ruleset
```

Other options (like `-n`) might also do it along other things.

This priority value comes from the priorities used historically by *iptables* or by Netfilter's own facilities and is described for example in *nftables*' wiki there: [Netfilter_hooks - Priority_within_hook](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Netfilter_hooks#Priority_within_hook)

> | nftables Families | Typical hooks | nft Keyword | Value | Netfilter Internal Priority | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | [...] |  |  |  |  |  |
> | inet, ip, ip6, arp, netdev | all | filter | 0 | NF_IP_PRI_FILTER | Filtering operation, the filter table |
> | [...] |  |  |  |  |  |

Also note that the priority isn't about chain priority in the same table, but chain priority in the same *hook*. Two chains in the same table but with different hooks (eg: `prerouting` or `forward`) won't ever get their priorities compared: the hook name already defines the order. Only chains within the same hook and family, even if not in the same table, will have their priority compared to know which chain is evaluated first. If you are using only one chain per hook in each family, then this value won't matter much. It still can matter with regard to Netfilter's own facilities: prerouting/defragmentation at -400, prerouting/conntrack operations at -200 etc.